# What is Salsa? Which Salsa is which?

Tags: comida

I was just eating some tortilla chips and salsa when I asked myself, "What is the difference between this salsa and something like `salsa de espagueti`?"

So far, I have yet to hear or read an emphasis on the type of `salsa` being made/used/eaten...  Whenever I search YouTube for "how to make salsa" or "¿cómo hacer salsa?" or "¿cómo hacer salsa italiana?", I get that same sauce that I would normally refer to as `marinana sauce`, in English.

### This is not a gastronomical question.

I am not asking how to make the salsa.  That is irrelevant.

Is there a correct way to distinguish between the `marinara sauce` I referred to earlier and the salsa you would use as a tortilla chip dip?

Tositos makes salsa dip, queso dip, all sorts of dips, but in Spanish it seems that are pretty much all considered `salsa`.

### It appears that,
All that is saucy is salsa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Salsa` can be understood as pretty much anything that you would put over food to make it more tasty, or any kind of juice involved in cooking.

The definition of [salsa](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=rFcNRgh0CDXX2VfSo0D3) explains that it is a composition of different edible substances used to season or dress the food.

I remember that when eating at my parents we would usually have a salad, and my father would ask

> Vas a mojar en la salsa?  <sub>Are you going to dip in the sauce?</sub>

even if the salad technically had an *aliño  <sub>(dressing)</sub>* made of oil and vinegar instead of a sauce, but the word *salsa* conveyed the message. A `salsa` in pretty much anything that you could use to dip, that's why all those sauces Tostitos makes are considered *salsas* in Spanish.

Due to this board meaning, the word *salsa* may be omitted when describing some dishes like in

> Espagueti con (salsa de) tomate

Answer (score 7):

`Salsa` is the Spanish word for `sauce`. The application method doesn't matter, so  `dips` are also `salsas`.

So, all dips and sauces are considered `salsas` and you distinguish them by adding words, as in `salsa de queso`, `salsa blanca`, `salsa mayonesa`, etc. Some don't even have `salsa` in their names, as `alioli`, `pesto` or `mostaza`.

Now, that company has a "just `salsa`" dip. Well, it can be anything. If there is a particular sauce known just as `salsa` in English, then probably that's it. I suspect it's some kind of sauce associated with Mexican food, such as `salsa roja`, `salsa verde`, or [`pico de gallo`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pico_de_gallo).

Comment: In American English, the loanword **salsa** always means **pico de gallo**. It's a bit odd as the Mexican speakers who brought the concept almost always mean **verde** or **rojo** when they use bare **salsa**, but Americans who don't speak Spanish don't eat much **verde** and **rojo**.

Answer (score 0):

The word salsa has a much wider meaning. There is salsa music and dance that has nothing to to do with food at all. The point of salsa music is that it is a mixture of a different dancing styles. Often with salsa music the word sabor is used (literally meaning taste). Again no connection to food whatsoever.
The citizens of the Mexico City are referred as Chilangos. One of the possible meanings of the word Chilango refers to salsa de chile. They are called Chilangos, because they are mixture of people coming from 16 different states of the Mexican Union and they mix together.
So my interpretation of the word salsa is that it is whatever that mixes together. Being it salsa de espagueti, salsa de totopos, or more generally people's cultures mixing together.